# position to custom html module

Tags: html, css, joomla, module

This is the template of joomla

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                         |
| position: top                           |
|                                         |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

I positioned to module "search" to top and "toplinks" to top and after editing css both "search" to `float: left;` and "toplinks" to `float: right;` and it worked like this

[image]

and after then I would like to give some other like image or homelinks or any other contents exactly below to as above picture like  this[image]

I would like to do this without editing in index.php because I need this some time in other page rather than front page. That is I would like to do from joomla. How to do ? Any idea, Should I make a banner or something else.

I tried making a module -> custom html but could not accomplish the position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your template's `index.php` to include 3 different module positions in the header, like

**my_template/index,php**

```
...
<div id="header">
    <div id="topbar">
        <div id="topbar-left"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbar-left" /></div>
        <div id="topbar-right"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbar-right" /></div>
        <?php if ($this->countModules('topbar-teaser') > 0) : ?>
           <div id="topbar-teaser"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="topbar-teaser" /></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

**CSS**

```
#topbar-left { float: left; }
#topbar-right { float: right; }
#topbar-teaser { clear: both; }
```

**Module**

Put your image into a Custom HTML module and publish it at position `topbar-teaser` on any pages you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply menu items you wish to add, create a new menu via the Menu Manager in the admin backend, then create some menu items for it. Once done, go to the Module Manager, create a new module and set the type to "menu". You can then select the menu you created and set the position to "toplinks".